# MATLAB: prediction bounds and constrained linear/nonlinear regression

Tags: matlab, constrained-regression

I'm struggling to fit the following rational function to data $(x_i,y_i)$:

$$\hat{f} (x) = \frac{1+p_1x+p_2x^2}{1+q_1x+(p_1+p_2-q_1)x^2}$$

The reason why I chose this model is a long story. Let's just say that I need that the function has no poles (i.e., the denominator has no roots) in the interval $I=[0,1]$. Now, this is guaranteed if

- $1+q_1>0$
- $1+p_1+p_2-q_1>0$

I'll skip the proof, but I can provide it if you're curious. Thus, I could follow approach 1:

1. solve this problem in MATLAB by using `fmincon` to fit $\hat{f}(x)$ under the two linear constraints stated above.

However, since I also have data in the form $(x_i,z_i/w_i)$, I could also follow an alternative route 2, made of two steps:

2. - fit a polynomial $\hat{p}(x)$ to $(x_i,z_i)$ (this is standard linear regression, thus `fitlm` will suffice)
   - I now have $(\hat{p_1},\hat{p_2})$. I can then fit polynomial $\hat{q}(x)=1+q_1+(\hat{p_1}+\hat{p_2}-q_1)x^2$, where now the only coefficient to be fitted is $q_1$, to data $(x_i,w_i)$, again under the two linear constraints stated before. `lsqlin` will do the job.

The second way is surely faster, as linear regression problems can be solved in a fraction of the time needed for nonlinear regression problems. What I don't like of both approaches, is that I will **not** get prediction bounds in either way. In the first case I don't get them, because `fmincon`is an optimization tool, which doesn't output any prediction bounds. In the second case I don't get them, because I can get prediction bounds for $\hat{p}(x)$ from `fitlm`, but there's no such output in `lsqlin`, and even if there was, I would still have prediction bounds separately for $\hat{p}(x)$  and $\hat{q}(x)$, but no idea how to translate them into prediction bounds for the ratio $\frac{\hat{p}(x)}{\hat{q}(x)}$.

So, questions!

- Which approach do you suggest, between 1. and 2.?
- Is there any way to get prediction bounds when doing constrained nonlinear regression, or the ratio of a unconstrained linear regression and a constrained one? I need to use MATLAB, but I'm a decent programmer, so I'm okay with coding some stuff myself, as long as it's not too complicated.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: To decide among these approaches--or any approach, for that matter--you need to consider the nature of the data and how you will model variation between them and your model. The two approaches are *profoundly* different in that regard. So, could you edit this question to elaborate on the nature of your data--explain what the $x_i,z_i,$ and $w_i$ are--as well as your intended utilization of the results?

Comment: @ DeltaIV, Is this question still active?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not answering before.  After @whuber correctly pointed out that I had to provide more details, I went back to the test guys which gave me the data, and I had to discuss a lot with them, to understand better where exactly $x_i, z_i, w_i$ came from (turns out it the answer is really complex). Now I'm abroad so it' hard for me to edit the question. Should I wait for next Saturday when I'm back, or shall I delete this question and write a new one in the next days?